# html() in ajax only load with first time

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, load

Laravel 5.
I load view from controller using ajax.
When load first time then everything okay.
But when press <kbd>f5</kbd> then it not work. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> then Okay.
I don't know what happen.
Please help me.
**Controller**

```
class TopSliderController extends Controller
{
  public function index(Request $request)
{
   return view('home.top_slider');
}
}
```

**My javascript**

```
(function($) { 
    load_view("/topic", "GET", "#test_top", []);
}(jQuery));

function load_view(url, method, field_id, param = []) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url, //+= '?_=' + (new Date()).getTime()
        method: method,
        data: {param},
        timeout: 10000,
        datatype: "html",
        success:function(result)
        {
           $(field_id).html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

**View**

```
<div id="test_top">

    </div>
```

Comment: try enclosing the function in  a $(document).ready() call

Comment: because you changed to element and there is no function attached anymore. Probably `innerhtml` will save you

Comment: with `ctrl + f5`, you reload the cache too, so try to set the `cache` parameter of ajax to `false` and you should be fine.

`cache: false,`

Comment: I try cache: false and innerhtml, but it still the same

Comment: Whats the response from the request when you refresh the page with `f5`?

Comment: I access to TopSliderController and return view('home.top_slider');

Comment: It's hard to bugfix if we don't know the content of your response.
Maybe you can make a `console.log(result);` when you reload with `ctrl + f5` and a second time when normal reaload with only `f5`. There must be a difference?

Comment: I have console.log(result). first and second the same.
I think issue at $(field_id).html(result); but i don't know what is it.